# How to Set the Loading Value for the Circular progresss Indicator like progress percentage for 60 days in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to Set the loading value for the Circular progresss indicator like progress percentage in flutter for 60 days-Math formula?I need this stuff for my flutter project,Sorry if i am asking something silly:-)
**Note**: I'm new to this amazing flutter development.

Comment: How do you mean for 60 days?

Comment: The total days-60 ,so the circular progress indicator value should've been increase day by day till 60 days can you help me out from this one? -ThankYou in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set "completed" rate of a progress indicator like this:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(value: 0.5)
```

The above will result in a 50% indicator. All you have to do is use a member as value in a `StatefulWidget` and use `setState` to update it according to the desired percentage.

Also you can use it to indicate the progress when loading an image:

```
Image.network(
  '<url>',
  height: 50,
  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
      ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
    if (loadingProgress == null) {
      return child;
    }
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
            ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
            : null,
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks man for your help

Comment: You are welcome!